# Why I am getting HttpRequestException: No such host is known. (youtube.com:443)

Tags: .net, azure

I have created this code.

```
 var url = Request.Form["Url"].ToString();
            var youtube = YouTube.Default;
            var vid = youtube.GetVideo(url);
            MP3Name = vid.FullName;
            return File(vid.GetBytes(), "application/octet-stream", MP3Name.ToString());
```

To Download youtube to mp4.

It is working locally.

After deploying to azure VM.

It is not working.

Note my VM has no internet connection

Here is my rules

[image]

Comment: How do you create an azure vm without internet connection? And even if that is possible, how do you think it would connect to some service on the internet without internet connection? Also resolving hostnames requires an internet connection.

Comment: If the VM has no internet connection why do you expect it to download files from the internet?

Comment: How Can I add internet connection to my VM @tymtam

Comment: I'm actually wondering how you managed to create an azure vm without internet connection. How do you even connect to a VM in the cloud that has no internet connection.

Comment: @derpirscher it is strange issue bro

Comment: @derpirscher any luck bro

Comment: @derpirscher any chance man

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you did to your VM to block it's internet access.

Comment: @derpirscher i ddi not do anything manj

Comment: @derpirscher any luck